# ssis12 script task works in Visual studio but fails in sql agent

Tags: c#, ssis

Update

I have removed try catch so any error will be exposed. And comment out statement by statement and finally locate the problem statement is

```
    WB = _Excel.Workbooks.Open("D:\\temp\\TempSSIS\\zip\\test.xlsx",
                        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                        Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

But don't know why. The folder D:\temp and all files or folders have been shared to Everyone with read/write permission.

Here is a pic of the execution report from SSIS catalog
[image]

---

I have a test SSIS (SQL Server 2012) project, which has one package, which has one script task only. In this script task:

```
    #region Help:  Introduction to the script task
    /* The Script Task allows you to perform virtually any operation that can be accomplished in
     * a .Net application within the context of an Integration Services control flow. 
     * 
     * Expand the other regions which have "Help" prefixes for examples of specific ways to use
     * Integration Services features within this script task. */
    #endregion


    #region Namespaces
    using System;
    using System.Data;
    using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
    #endregion

    namespace ST_c4cb3478c68843fca41e6f241a1431b4
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// ScriptMain is the entry point class of the script.  Do not change the name, attributes,
        /// or parent of this class.
        /// </summary>
        [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
        public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
        {
            #region Help:  Using Integration Services variables and parameters in a script
            /* To use a variable in this script, first ensure that the variable has been added to 
             * either the list contained in the ReadOnlyVariables property or the list contained in 
             * the ReadWriteVariables property of this script task, according to whether or not your
             * code needs to write to the variable.  To add the variable, save this script, close this instance of
             * Visual Studio, and update the ReadOnlyVariables and 
             * ReadWriteVariables properties in the Script Transformation Editor window.
             * To use a parameter in this script, follow the same steps. Parameters are always read-only.
             * 
             * Example of reading from a variable:
             *  DateTime startTime = (DateTime) Dts.Variables["System::StartTime"].Value;
             * 
             * Example of writing to a variable:
             *  Dts.Variables["User::myStringVariable"].Value = "new value";
             * 
             * Example of reading from a package parameter:
             *  int batchId = (int) Dts.Variables["$Package::batchId"].Value;
             *  
             * Example of reading from a project parameter:
             *  int batchId = (int) Dts.Variables["$Project::batchId"].Value;
             * 
             * Example of reading from a sensitive project parameter:
             *  int batchId = (int) Dts.Variables["$Project::batchId"].GetSensitiveValue();
             * */

            #endregion

            #region Help:  Firing Integration Services events from a script
            /* This script task can fire events for logging purposes.
             * 
             * Example of firing an error event:
             *  Dts.Events.FireError(18, "Process Values", "Bad value", "", 0);
             * 
             * Example of firing an information event:
             *  Dts.Events.FireInformation(3, "Process Values", "Processing has started", "", 0, ref fireAgain)
             * 
             * Example of firing a warning event:
             *  Dts.Events.FireWarning(14, "Process Values", "No values received for input", "", 0);
             * */
            #endregion

            #region Help:  Using Integration Services connection managers in a script
            /* Some types of connection managers can be used in this script task.  See the topic 
             * "Working with Connection Managers Programatically" for details.
             * 
             * Example of using an ADO.Net connection manager:
             *  object rawConnection = Dts.Connections["Sales DB"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);
             *  SqlConnection myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)rawConnection;
             *  //Use the connection in some code here, then release the connection
             *  Dts.Connections["Sales DB"].ReleaseConnection(rawConnection);
             *
             * Example of using a File connection manager
             *  object rawConnection = Dts.Connections["Prices.zip"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);
             *  string filePath = (string)rawConnection;
             *  //Use the connection in some code here, then release the connection
             *  Dts.Connections["Prices.zip"].ReleaseConnection(rawConnection);
             * */
            #endregion


            /// <summary>
            /// This method is called when this script task executes in the control flow.
            /// Before returning from this method, set the value of Dts.TaskResult to indicate success or failure.
            /// To open Help, press F1.
            /// </summary>
            public void Main()
            {

                Excel.Application _Excel = null;
                Excel.Workbook WB = null;
                Excel.Worksheet WS;

                try
                {

                    _Excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                    WB = _Excel.Workbooks.Open("D:\\temp\\TempSSIS\\zip\\test.xlsx",
                        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                        Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

                    //do something
                    WB.Password = "123";
                    WB.SaveAs("D:\\temp\\TempSSIS\\zip\\test_1.xlsx");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    WB.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    GC.Collect();
                    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(WB);

                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(_Excel);


                }

                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
            }

            #region ScriptResults declaration
            /// <summary>
            /// This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of this class for setting the
            /// result of the script.
            /// 
            /// This code was generated automatically.
            /// </summary>
            enum ScriptResults
            {
                Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
                Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
            };
            #endregion

        }
    }
```

The script opens a existing excel file and adds password to the excel. This works fine in VS but fails when I run it from SQL Server job agent. The job runs on sql server agent account, which has access to the file. The error message from job agent:

Message
Executed as user: BCSGRS\SQLService. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 11.0.3381.0 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.    Started:  14:36:03  Package execution on IS Server failed. Execution ID: 70, Execution Status:4.  To view the details for the execution, right-click on the Integration Services Catalog, and open the [All Executions] report  Started:  14:36:03  Finished: 14:36:07  Elapsed:  4.196 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.

Only thing I found in the report in Integration services catalogue is Script Task:Error: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Comment: Try running it in Visual Studio as BCSGRS\SQLService.

Comment: Can you log the details of the error by using Dts.Events.FireError in your catch?  Do you have excel or the access drivers installed on the server

Comment: @TabAlleman The account was installed by a third party company, I wouldn't bother to ask for the password for that account for now.

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz Excel is installed on the server. I have updated my post.

Comment: Please remove the try catch and post the stack trace

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz How can I get a stack trace since I am running it in sql agent and it runs fine in VS? I have attached a screen from the execution report from SSIS catalog.

Comment: Won't SQL agent show unhandled exceptions in the error messages returned to it?  If not, use the try catch and log the Exception and inner exceptions using Dts.Events.FireError()